# Getting the index of all vowels and place "ub" in front of them (except the last vowel)

Tags: java, string, replace

get string input from user, then get the indexes of all the vowels (a,e,i,o,u), then place "ub" in front of all of them except the last vowel.

managed the user string input, and getting the index of all the vowels, but i cant 'inject' the ub in front of the vowels

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment_2_Q2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("\\\\-------------------------------------------------------\r\n" + 
                "\\\\       English to Ubbi Dubbi Translator Program\r\n" + 
                "\\\\------------------------------------------------------------------");

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


        String input_user = kb.nextLine();
        String output_user ;
        String ubbi = "ub";


        for (int i = 0; i<input_user.length(); i++)
        {
             if(input_user.charAt(i) == 'a'|| input_user.charAt(i) == 'e'|| input_user.charAt(i) == 'i' || input_user.charAt(i) == 'o' || input_user.charAt(i) == 'u') 
             {
                 System.out.println("Given string contains "+input_user.charAt(i)+" at the index "+i);

             }

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: `output_user = input_user.replaceAll("[aeiou](?=[^aeiou]*[aeiou])", ubbi + "$0");` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/NBjyKK/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
    String[] searchList={"a","e","i","o","u"};
    String[] replacementList={"uba","ube","ubi","ubo","ubu"};
    input_user=StringUtils.replaceEach(input_user,  searchList, replacementList);
    System.out.println(input_user);
```

**Input:**

```
aeiou
```

**Output:**

```
ubaubeubiuboubu
```

Use string utils. Its more readable and easy to understand.